Docker - can't ping or telnet any port from any container to the host machine (windows 11)
I have docker installed on windows 11
I can't ping the host machine from inside any container
Telnet from any container doesn't connect to any port on the host machine
This was working fine for over a year now, but suddenly it stopped, I'm not sure if it was an update that caused this or what.
To keep it simple, I created a new ubuntu container with bridged network
1a6070345c6e   ubuntu_default        bridge    local
I disabled the firewall on the host machine
I then tried to ping the host machine, with no success
> root@350629447ec5:/# ping 192.168.100.100
> PING 192.168.100.100 (192.168.100.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
> ^C
> 192.168.100.100 ping statistics --- 131 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 135229ms

Then I tried with telnet:
> root@350629447ec5:/# telnet 192.168.100.100 80
> Trying 192.168.100.100...

As I mentioned, this was working before, how can I debug and solve this issue?


The host has a different IP-number seen from a container.

Why are you trying to send ICMP packets, or use the plain-text Telnet protocol?  Is there any relevant application code you could include in your question?

To access the host from a container, the recommended way is to add --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway to your docker run command. Then you can use the hostname host.docker.internal to access it.
Like this
docker run --rm -it --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway debian

and then inside the container you can
ping host.docker.internal

(you need to install ping first if you use the debian image in my example)
